# Confused over a line in L&L Quantum Mechanics (non-relativistic) involving linear algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, linear-algebra

So I was reading *Quantum Mechanics: Non-relativistic Theory* by Landau and Lifshitz when I came across this line (Edition 2, page 10):

$$\hat{f} \Psi = \sum_n{a_n f_n \Psi_n},$$

where $\Psi = \sum_n a_n \Psi_n$ and $\hat{f} \Psi_n = f_n \Psi_n$.

I tried understanding this line a bit better by making an analogy with $\Psi$ as a vector in Euclidean space and $\hat{f}$ a matrix, etc., but can't recover this relation. By the way, I can follow the derivation they use in the book, but was trying to understand this on a more intuitive level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation might be a little confusing: the vectors $\Psi_n$ are the [eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of the operator $\hat{f}$, as can be seen by the relation: $$\hat{f}\Psi_n = f_n \Psi_n.$$ The numbers $f_n$ are the **eigenvalues** associated with the eigenvectors $\Psi_n$.

If $\hat{f}$ is a Hermitian operator (which are used to represent physical observables in Quantum Mechanics), then we are guaranteed that its eigenvectors form a **complete basis**, meaning that any arbitrary vector in the space can be written as a linear combination of these vectors. Thus, an arbitrary vector $\Psi$ can be written as: $$\Psi = a_0 \Psi_0 + a_1 \Psi_1 + a_2 \Psi_2 + ... = \sum_n a_n \Psi_n.$$

We can now combine the above two relations using the fact that the operator $\hat{f}$ is **[linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)#Linear_operators)**. Therefore,

$$\hat{f}\Psi = \hat{f}\Bigg( \sum_n a_n \Psi_n \Bigg) = \sum_n a_n \hat{f}\Psi_n = \sum_n a_n f_n \Psi_n.$$

Comment: Oh wow, that was actually really simple. I don't know why I didn't think to use the linearity of $\hat{f}$. Thank you so much!